# Showing a "back-to-top"-button after scrolling a certain amount

Tags: javascript, html, css, comparative-review

I have a "back to top"-button on the page, It should be visible after the user has scrolled a certain amount<sup>*</sup>.

This means I have to add or remove a class `active` every now and then.

I have two solutions:

1. Update the class on every scroll.
2. Test whether the class is set/ not et and then test, whether it is necessary to interact.

The setup:

```
this.button = document.querySelector('.some-class');

window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
  this.onScroll(event);
});
```

The long version, which does add or remove the class only if needed:

```
onScroll(event) {
  if (
    !this.button.classList.contains('active') &&
    (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100)
  ) {
    this.button.classList.add('active');
  }

  if (
    this.button.classList.contains('active') &&
    (document.body.scrollTop <= 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 100)
  ) {
    this.button.classList.remove('is-active');
  }
}
```

The alternativ short version, that adds or removes the class everytime:

```
onScroll(event) {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    this.button.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    this.button.classList.remove('active');
  } 
}
```

My questions are:

- Does the longer version have a better performance?
- Does the browser optimize it itself – i.e. in the short version if the class is already present, it doesn't repaint?

<sub><sup>*</sup> For simplicity this value is hard-coded here. It's a variable in the implemented version.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the longer version have a better performance?

No, the longer version has two different `if` conditions and you're recalculating the scroll area twice (i.e.: `document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100` and `document.body.scrollTop <= 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 100`)

---

> Does the browser optimize it itself – i.e. in the short version if the class is already present, it doesn't repaint?

Yes, if the class name already exists it'll simply be ignored.

[classList MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods):

> add( String [, String [, ...]] )
>
> Adds the specified class values. If these classes already exist in the element's class attribute they are **ignored**.

---

Handling the scroll event *can* be performant heavy if you have a complex handler as the scroll event will be *continuously* fired during a scroll.

If you wish to optimize your scroll event handler, I would *highly* recommend using `setTimeout`. This allows your script to **ONLY** be called once the scroll has ended and skips doing your "heavy" condition checking for every scroll tick.

```js
let setTimeoutId = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
  //clear a previously pending timeout
  clearTimeout(setTimeoutId);
  //create a new timeout that will be launched in 400ms
  setTimeoutId = setTimeout(()=>onScroll(event), 100);
});

function onScroll(event){
  console.log("On scroll called");
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. For the last part: We already use a `pipe|throttler|debouncer` in our production code (depending on the project's framework). I just didn't wanted to bloat the question.